# Dua for an early Marriage

Tags: salat, nikah, dua

I am a woman  an only daughter, I have been engaged for about 3years  now my fiance and I are ready for marriage but my father inlaw keeps delaying our wedding because of irrelevant reason, also my dowry was paid early this year, yet no date for wedding.  I want to get married this year, am tired of staying single I need dua.

Comment: You could just make dua in your own words. You don't need a special prescribed dua, and I am not sure such a dua exists.

Comment: I would recommend you to get another person to help. like a nearby Alim or sheikh, to talk to your dad about this matter.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, there aren't any specific dua's from the quran or sunnah for getting married, and it doesn't seem that your problem is finding a match but expiditing the arrangements you have. So there are some du'a that may usefully help you ask in your circumstances. I'd recommend studying the quran for the context and lessons behind these du'a.

The dua of Musa alaihi as salaam in Surah Al Qasas [28:24]:

> رَبِّ إِنِّي لِمَا أَنزَلْتَ إِلَيَّ مِنْ خَيْرٍ فَقِيرٌ
>
> “O my Sus­tainer! Verily, in dire need am I of any good which Thou mayest bestow upon me!”

The du'a of Ayyub alaihi as salaam in surah Al Anbiya [21:83]:

> أَنِّي مَسَّنِيَ الضُّرُّ وَأَنتَ أَرْحَمُ الرَّاحِمِينَ
>
> Verily, distress has seized me, and You are the Most Merciful of all those who show mercy

The du'a of bearing hardship with patience in Surah al-A'raf [7:126]:

> رَبَّنَا أَفْرِغْ عَلَيْنَا صَبْرًا وَتَوَفَّنَا مُسْلِمِينَ
>
> Our Lord! pour out on us patience, and cause us to die as Muslims

And from the sunnah, if you find your matter has become difficult to progress, from Hisnul-Muslim:

> اللَّهمَّ لا سَهْلَ إِلاَّ مَا جَعَلتَه ُُ سَهْلا، ً وَأَنْتَ تَجْعَلُ الحَزَنَ إِذَا شِئْتَ سَهْلا
>
> ‘O Allah, there is no ease except in that which You have made easy, and You make the difficulty, if You wish, easy.’

Also, if your mahr has been paid, I wouldn't spend it; maybe the du'a that would be most useful to you - is [the du'a of istikhara](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/2217/how-to-pray-istikhaarah): 3 years seems pretty unreasonable; maybe you need to return this mahr and move on.

Answer (score -1):

There is no special dua for early marriage but you can make dua anytime to Allah.For Every dua is accrepted either in this world or hereafter.they are some special ocassion for dua.

1 – Laylat al-Qadar. It was narrated that ‘Aa’ishah asked the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him): “If I know what night is Laylat al-Qadar, what should I say during it?” He said: “Say: Allaahumma innaka ‘afuwwan tuhibb ul-‘afwa fa’fu ‘anni (O Allaah, You are forgiving and love forgiveness, so forgive me).”

2 – Du’aa’ in the depths of the night, the time before dawn, the time when Allaah descends to bestow His bounty upon His slaves, to meet their needs and to relieve their distress, when He says: “Who will call upon Me, that I may answer Him? Who will ask of Me, that I may give him? Who will seek My forgiveness, that I may forgive him?” narrated by al-Bukhaari, 1145.

3 – Following the prescribed prayers. According to the hadeeth of Abu Umaamah, it was said: “O Messenger of Allaah, which du’aa’ is heard?” He said: “In the last third of the night, and following the prescribed prayers.” Narrated by al-Tirmidhi, 3499; classed as hasan by al-Albaani in Saheeh al-Tirmidhi.
4 – Between the adhaan and the iqaamah. It is narrated in a saheeh report that the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “A du’aa’ offered between the adhaan and iqaamah is not rejected.” Narrated by Abu Dawood (521) and al-Tirmidhi (212). See also Saheeh al-Jaami’, 2408.

5 – When the call for the prescribed prayers is given and when the ranks are drawn up for battle, as it says in the marfoo’ hadeeth of Sahl ibn Sa’d: “There are two that will not be rejected, or will rarely be rejected: du’aa’ at the time of the call for prayer and at the time of battle when the fighting begins.” Narrated by Abu Dawood; it is a saheeh report. See Saheeh al-Jaami’, 3079.

6 – When rain falls, as it said in the hadeeth of Sahl ibn Sa’d that is attributed to the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him): “There are two which will not be rejected: du’aa’ at the time of the call (to prayer) and when it is raining.” Narrated by Abu Dawood and classed as saheeh by al-Albaani in Saheeh al-Jaami’ (3078).

7 – At a certain time of the night, as the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “During the night there is a time when the Muslim does not ask for the good of this world and the Hereafter but it will be given to him, and that happens every night.” Narrated by Muslim, 757.

8 – A certain time on Friday.  The Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) mentioned Friday and said: “During it there is a time when a Muslim slave does not stand and pray and ask Allaah for something, but He will give it to him,” and he gestured with his hand to indicate how short that time is. Narrated by al-Bukhaari, 935; Muslim, 852. See also question no. 21748.

9 – When drinking Zamzam water. It was narrated from Jaabir (may Allaah be pleased with him) that the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “Zamzam water is for that for which it is drunk.” Narrated by Ahmad and classed as saheeh by al-Albaani in Saheeh al-Jaami’, 5502.

10 – When prostrating. The Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “The closest that a person is to his Lord is when he is prostrating, so say a great deal of du’aa’ then.” Narrated by Muslim, 482.

11 – When hearing the crowing of a rooster, because of the hadeeth: “When you hear the crowing of a rooster, ask Allaah of His bounty, for he has seen an angel.” Narrated by al-Bukhaari, 2304; Muslim, 2729.

12 – When saying the du’aa’, “Laa ilaaha illa anta, subhaanaka, inni kuntu min al-zaalimeen ([none has the right to be worshipped but You (O Allaah)], Glorified (and Exalted) be You [above all that (evil) they associate with You]! Truly, I have been of the wrongdoers – cf al-Anbiya’ 21:87]).” It was narrated in a saheeh hadeeth that the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “The prayer of Dhu’l-Noon (Yoonus) which he said when he was in the belly of the whale: ‘Laa ilaaha illa anta, subhaanaka, inni kuntu min al-zaalimeen ([none has the right to be worshipped but You (O Allaah)], Glorified (and Exalted) be You [above all that (evil) they associate with You]! Truly, I have been of the wrongdoers.’ No Muslim recites this du’aa’ concerning any matter but Allaah will answer him.” Narrated by al-Tirmidhi and classed as saheeh in Saheeh al-Jaami’, 3383.